# run .sh file from python spyder in windows

Tags: python, windows

Please help me to run `.sh` file (bash file) from Python Spyder IDE in windows. I am using the below code.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./test.sh'])
```

I am facing the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I do not know where I have to keep `test.sh` file in windows.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is going to be any easy way to run a shell script file on Windows (from Python or otherwise), since you probably don't have a Unix shell program available to run it.

Comment: How about just rewriting the shell script into Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`change dir` while calling the `test.sh` file :

First, install Git (https://git-scm.com/downloads)

```
>>> import os
>>> from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
>>> os.chdir("path of test.sh file")
>>> p = Popen(["filename"], shell=True, stdout = PIPE)
```

There is some security consideration plz read this:

([Using subprocess.Popen to run a batch file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129847/using-subprocess-popen-to-run-a-batch-file-in-windows/51131358#51131358))

and read comment session also

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I did the same but it is not working for me.Have you tried to do the same in windows?

Comment: Now I am getting error:  OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: you should have` git bash` installed

Comment: Even with git bash or cygwin installed, the python script must be ran within that, not directly from the Windows Python installation because Popen will attempt to use CMD

Comment: Thanks.I am running it directly from Spyder IDE and its working fine after installing git bash.Now i want to run textcleaner Image magick commands.Do you have any idea how to run it?