# Using subprocess.Popen to run a batch file in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, subprocess

Why can we not use `Popen` to run a batch file?

```
>>> p = Popen(["filename"], shell=True, stdout = PIPE)
```

This is working well, but according to the documentation we should not use `shell = True` for "running a batch file or console-based executable".

Why can't we use `shell = True` when it runs a batch file? Why should it only be used for building in cmd?

Comment: I don't understand why running the bat file using python code will duplicate it

Comment: FYI, `shell=True` should not be used with an args list. Pass a command-line string. Passing a list in this case is completely wrong in Unix, but also problematic in Windows. An args list is always converted to a command line in Windows via `subprocess.list2cmdline`. The problem is that it builds a command line that's intended for C/C++ programs or programs that call `CommandLineToArgvW`. The CMD shell uses different syntax.

Comment: What the documentation means by including "console-based executable" is that the shell is not required to run console apps. This is there I think to clear up a confusion that some novice programmers have. They mistakenly think that the CMD shell is actually the console, but CMD is just another "console-based executable" that *uses* a console. If a console app doesn't inherit a console, startup code in kernelbase.dll simply allocates a new one. The details of that are an implementation detail that varies between Windows versions.

Comment: What the documentation means by including "running a batch file" is that the underlying `CreateProcess` rewrites the command line to use the shell automatically if the file extension  is .BAT or .CMD. So you don't need `shell=True` to run a batch script. However the same security precautions need to be taken since ultimately the command is run via `cmd /c`.

Comment: Thanks Now I understand Thanks for the information @eryksun

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174189/discussion-between-hitesh-gorana-and-eryksun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `subprocess.Popen()` with the `shell` parameter set to `True` in production is a generally bad idea. One of the dangers include [shell injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_injection#Shell_injection) vulnerabilities, as quoted by the Python 3 docs:

> **17.5.2. Security Considerations**
>
> Unlike some other popen functions, this implementation will never implicitly call 
>     a system shell. This
>   means that all characters, including shell metacharacters, can safely
>   be passed to child processes. If the shell is invoked explicitly, via
>   `shell=True`, it is the application’s responsibility to ensure that all
>   whitespace and metacharacters are quoted appropriately to avoid shell
>   injection vulnerabilities.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html